# Fatal error: Class 'CI_Upload' not found

Tags: codeigniter, upload

```
$config['upload_path'] = './content/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $this->load->library('MY_Upload');
         $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
        "file_name"     => array("file_1.jpg", "file_2.jpg", "file_3.jpg"),
        "upload_path"   => "./content/"
    ));

        if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("userfile")){
           print_r($this->upload->get_multi_upload_data());
        }
```

I've used this code for multiple upload, but is not working, Fatal error: Class 'CI_Upload' not found, error is of this type.

Comment: you should not load library `MY_Upload` this way..., suppose you want to extend `CI_Upload` from `MY_Upload` custom uploaded library.., you should load this way `$this->load->library('upload');` `CI` auto priority of `MY_Upload`

Answer (score 1):

Extending Native Libraries

If all you need to do is add some functionality to an existing library - perhaps add a function or two - then it's overkill to replace the entire library with your version. In this case it's better to simply extend the class. Extending a class is nearly identical to replacing a class with a couple exceptions:

```
The class declaration must extend the parent class.
Your new class name and filename must be prefixed with MY_ (this item is configurable. See below.).
```

For example, to extend the native Email class you'll create a file named application/libraries/MY_Email.php, and declare your class with:

```
class MY_Upload extends CI_Upload {

    }
```

Note: If you need to use a constructor in your class make sure you extend the parent constructor:

```
    class MY_Upload extends CI_Upload {

            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }
public function some_function()
{

}
        }
```

Loading Your Sub-class

To load your sub-class you'll use the standard syntax normally used. DO NOT include your prefix. For example, to load the example above, which extends the Email class, you will use:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
```

Once loaded you will use the class variable as you normally would for the class you are extending. In the case of the email class all calls will use:

```
$this->upload->some_function();
```

I think you are understanding  Extending Native Libraries

you can change your code like this

```
$config['upload_path'] = './content/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
/************* i am changing only loading class only *********************/
        $this->load->library('upload');

         $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
        "file_name"     => array("file_1.jpg", "file_2.jpg", "file_3.jpg"),
        "upload_path"   => "./content/"
    ));

        if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("userfile")){
           print_r($this->upload->get_multi_upload_data());
        }
```